# Почему не работает значение max-width?

Tags: css, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

на сайте https://smartbalance.online стоит плагин **Buy one click WooCommerce**

жёлтая кнопка в товарах купить в один клик

хочу увеличить ширину попап окна до 960px
я добавил значения

```css
 #formOrderOneClick>.popup {
 max-width: 960px;
 width: auto;
 
}
```

почему не срабатывает значение  **max-width**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max-width - задает максимальное значение, но не устанавливает его.
Просто поставь: width: 960px;